# React Native: Typing in a search bar re-renders flat list and closes keyboard on every input

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have a list of posts in react native that I am rendering in a flat list. At the top of the screen there is a search bar (react native paper). The problem I am having is that whenever I update what is inside the search bar (every key press) the act of updating the filter and re-rendering the flat list closes the keyboard, interrupting the user.

```js
export function AnnouncementsScreen({ navigation }) {
    const { editMode, setEditMode, selectedPost, setSelectedPost, openDetailedView, openEditView } =
        useContext(AnnouncementsNavigatorContext)
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const { companyPosts, status } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.companyPosts)
    const { dark: isDark, colors } = useTheme()


    const [filter, setFilter] = useState<Filter>({
        ...filterInitialState,
    })

    const { sortedPosts } = useSortedCompanyPosts(filter)



    const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }: { item: CompanyPost }) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginBottom: 10 }} key={item.post_id}>
                <Post post={item} expanded={false} navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
        )
    }, [])

    

    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <View style={[styles.header, { borderColor: colors.border, backgroundColor: colors.card }]}>
                <Searchbar
                    placeholder="Search posts"
                    onChangeText={(value) => setFilter({ ...filter, search: value })}
                    value={filter.search}
                    style={[styles.input, { backgroundColor: isDark ? colors.background : '#E0E0E0' }]}
                />
                <View style={styles.buttonGroup}>
                    <Button
                        content="All"
                        color={filter.important ? colors.card : colors.primary}
                        _content={{ color: !filter.important ? 'white' : colors.primary }}
                        _button={{
                            borderColor: colors.border,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                            borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            filter.important &&
                                setFilter({
                                    ...filter,
                                    important: false,
                                })
                        }}
                    />
                    <Button
                        content="Important"
                        color={!filter.important ? colors.card : colors.primary}
                        _content={{ color: filter.important ? 'white' : colors.primary }}
                        _button={{
                            borderColor: colors.border,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                            borderLeftWidth: 0,
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            !filter.important &&
                                setFilter({
                                    ...filter,
                                    important: true,
                                })
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    windowSize={3}
                    initialNumToRender={7}
                    refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={handleRefresh} />}
                    data={sortedPosts}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    style={styles.flatList}
                    ListEmptyComponent={<AnnouncementsEmptyState />}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.post_id.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I have tried work arounds like having a temporary filter state that updates the real filter when the keyboard closes, i would prefer it to update in real time

Comment: Can you create a bare minimum in Expo snack?

Answer (score 0):

I think first off you need to add a keyExtractor on your FlatList or a key prop on your render item that is unique per item. This will help with re-rendering the list items if they are already rendered.

Example:

```
<FlatList
 keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}  <<<<<<<<< This Line needs to be added
 windowSize={3}
 initialNumToRender={7}
 refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={handleRefresh} />}
 data={sortedPosts}
 renderItem={renderItem}
 style={styles.flatList}
 ListEmptyComponent={<AnnouncementsEmptyState />}
 keyExtractor={(item) => item.post_id.toString()}
/>
```

I haven't used React Native Paper before but I think the problem with your keyboard flicker is the fact that you are keeping the state outside of the input component. I would suggest letting the input keep track of its state and just call back out for filter updates. I think that should solve your problem.

Example:

```
export function AnnouncementsScreen({ navigation }) {
    const { editMode, setEditMode, selectedPost, setSelectedPost, openDetailedView, openEditView } =
        useContext(AnnouncementsNavigatorContext)
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const { companyPosts, status } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.companyPosts)
    const { dark: isDark, colors } = useTheme()


    const [filter, setFilter] = useState<Filter>({
        ...filterInitialState,
    })

    const { sortedPosts } = useSortedCompanyPosts(filter)



    const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }: { item: CompanyPost }) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginBottom: 10 }} key={item.post_id}>
                <Post post={item} expanded={false} navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
        )
    }, [])

    

    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <View style={[styles.header, { borderColor: colors.border, backgroundColor: colors.card }]}>
                <Searchbar
                    placeholder="Search posts"
                    onChangeText={(value) => setFilter({ ...filter, search: value })}
                    defaultValue={filter.search}
                    style={[styles.input, { backgroundColor: isDark ? colors.background : '#E0E0E0' }]}
                />
                <View style={styles.buttonGroup}>
                    <Button
                        content="All"
                        color={filter.important ? colors.card : colors.primary}
                        _content={{ color: !filter.important ? 'white' : colors.primary }}
                        _button={{
                            borderColor: colors.border,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                            borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            filter.important &&
                                setFilter({
                                    ...filter,
                                    important: false,
                                })
                        }}
                    />
                    <Button
                        content="Important"
                        color={!filter.important ? colors.card : colors.primary}
                        _content={{ color: filter.important ? 'white' : colors.primary }}
                        _button={{
                            borderColor: colors.border,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                            borderLeftWidth: 0,
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            !filter.important &&
                                setFilter({
                                    ...filter,
                                    important: true,
                                })
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                <FlatList
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    windowSize={3}
                    initialNumToRender={7}
                    refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={handleRefresh} />}
                    data={sortedPosts}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    style={styles.flatList}
                    ListEmptyComponent={<AnnouncementsEmptyState />}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.post_id.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

basically the only change is changing the value prop on the text input to defaultValue which should only set the value on mount after that its value is internally controlled.

Hope that helps.